# How to layout multiple Floating Action Buttons in Vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'd like to have two floating action buttons in the lower right corner, one above the other (like google maps).

Currently I'm using a fixed style bottom offset to do this on one of the buttons, like so:

```
<v-btn fab fixed bottom right>...</v-btn>
<v-btn fab fixed bottom right style="bottom: 90px">...</v-btn>
```

...to achieve this, but I don't want to hardcode the 90px, I'd really rather say "I want two Floating Action Buttons, one vertically above the other".

Is there a vuetify-way to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put them inside another element with a bit of custom CSS for positioning:

```
<template>
  <v-layout column class="fab-container">
    <v-btn fab>
      <v-icon>add</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn fab>
      <v-icon>remove</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<style>
  .fab-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
</style>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyJzQP?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a class tag like this:

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text style="height: 100px; position: relative">
      <v-fab-transition>
        <v-btn color="grey" dark absolute top right fab small>
          <v-icon>mdi-bookmark-outline</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-fab-transition>
      <v-spacer />
      <v-fab-transition>
        <v-btn color="grey" dark absolute top right fab small class="mr-6">
          <v-icon>mdi-heart-outline</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-fab-transition>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>
```